# In vim, how do I copy the regular expression pattern?

Tags: regex, vim, replace

Sometimes I do a regexp search with `/`. But then I want to use the same pattern to do a replace, with `%s`. How do I copy or otherwise reuse the pattern?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

for example, you did a

```
/foo
```

then you could:

```
%s//bar/g
```

vim will replace all `foo` (your last search) with `bar`

Your last search pattern was stored in `/` register, you could get it by reading the register value. e.g.

```
"/p (in normal mode)
```

or

```
<c-r>/ (in insert/command mode)
```

Comment: Nice. This is like 3 answers in one. I should've remembered registers!